# Angular Material Dialog appears again

Tags: angular

I have an issue with Angular Material Dialog. 
When I open it, it's using the function and after I close it - everything is okay.
But when I'm changing page (via routing in angular) - this dialog is opening again twice, and when I change page (again via routing in angular) dialog appears again, but not twice (everytime dialog is multiplied). 
You can see images on this link : https://i.stack.imgur.com/DfT8a.jpg.
Code you can find here : https://pastebin.pl/view/28457001 
Sorry for my English and thanks for help anyway.

**EDIT: 
Solved a problem using .unsubscribe in ngOnDestroy. But anyway thanks for answer, it really helps me.**

Comment: Please, post some code. Anyway you can simply use `OnDesotry` life-cycle to set to false the variable that let you show/hide programmatically that modal.

Comment: As Jacopo said, it's always helpful to post code as people can be more direct about questions/solutions. The problem with the Dialog is that when you navigate to a different page using the browser buttons, it doesn't trigger itself to close. So in the OnDestroy lifecycle, as Jacopo said, call dialogRef.close() where dialogRef is whatever you named your dialog in your code. https://angular.io/api/core/OnDestroy

Comment: Sure, here is a link https://pastebin.pl/view/28457001 .
And can u show me example how to use OnDestroy?

Comment: Here is an example https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ng-on-destroy-fn?file=src%2Fapp%2Fon-destroy-method%2Fon-destroy-method.component.ts . In yours you would just call dialogRef.close() instead of the console.log

Comment: I did this early, but it didn't help  and also I got an errors. Maybe, I put it in the wrong place ( I need to put it in Dialog Component or in component from which I open dialog?).

Comment: You need to put it in the component from which you open the dialog. So when that component is destroyed (you hitting the back button), it closes the dialog

Comment: @canpan, But I can't put dialogRef.close() in ngOnDestroy, because it can't find dialogRef (dialogRef is finding in function openDialog()).

Comment: Could it be that I didn't unsubscribed in ngOnDestroy?
Because I'm using  function `.subscribe` from rxJs

Answer (score 0):

Try to set the dialog-reference to undefined when closed, see here:

```
 this.dialogRef.afterClosed().pipe(
    finalize(() => this.dialogRef = undefined)
  );
```

Answer (score 0):

For the close on navigation part of the question (and it may fix your other issue):

[Material Dialog API](https://material.angular.io/components/dialog/api) provides an option to close the dialog on navigation

Try adding `closeOnNavigation: true` as seen below using your code as an example

```
const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(FourthPageDialogComponent, {
  disableClose: true,
  data: { selectorFirst: resp['alertFreq'], selectorSecond: resp['conditionalAlert'], sliderFirst: this.sliderFirst, sliderSecond: this.sliderSecond, user: this.user},
  closeOnNavigation: true // Try adding me!
});
```